# error result in if statement in vb.net 2010

Tags: vb.net

the program execute the first part of if statement to all (type) and don't take another possibilities..
the code ;

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim cost As Integer
    Dim total As Integer
    Dim type As String

    type = ComboBox1.Text
    cost = CInt(TextBox3.Text)
    total = TextBox1.Text

    If type = "A" And (cost >= 5000 and cost <= 10000) Then
        TextBox5.Text = (total - ((total * 30) / 100))
        Label7.Text = "30%"
    ElseIf type = "A" And (cost >= 3000 and cost <= 4000) Then
        TextBox5.Text = (total - ((total * 20) / 100))
        Label7.Text = "20%"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf (type = "B" And (4000 >= cost <= 6000)) Then
        TextBox5.Text = (total - (total * 10 / 100))
        Label7.Text = "10%"
    ElseIf (type = "B" And (1000 >= cost <= 4000)) Then
        TextBox5.Text = (total - (total * 5 / 100))
        Label7.Text = "5%"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf (type = "C" And (3000 >= cost <= 5000)) Then
        TextBox5.Text = (total - (total * 3 / 100))
        Label7.Text = "3%"
    ElseIf (type = "C" And (1000 >= cost <= 3000)) Then
        TextBox5.Text = (total - (total * 2 / 100))
        Label7.Text = "2%"

    End If
End Sub
```

i hope find answer for this problem..

Comment: What is the error ?? show it in the question

Answer (score 0):

The reason this isn't working is because you are assigning the type variable to ComboBox.Text. The Text property is just text associated with the control, not the selected text. 
To get the selected text you need to access the SelectedText property:

```
type = ComboBox1.SelectedText
```

Also, I would recommend using a standard naming convention for your UI elements that is descriptive. eg. txtCost, lblPrice, cbType (for combo boxes)